# How to load large number of images in recyclerview?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview

I have an activity where user is allowed to select around 500 images and then moves to next activity where those images will populated in a RecyclerView, how should i make it all work, for smooth user experience and better performance.

Currently i'm passing the images as bitmaps using intents.

I'm using the photopicker library for photo selection, here user is allowed to select multiple images and the filepath of all the selected images gets stored in a string Arraylist, which gets returned in the onActivityResult of the activity, i'm storing the result in mUserSelectedPhotos named string arraylist below is some code for reference.

PhotoPickingActivity.java

```
mPickImagesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhotoPicker.builder()
                    .setPhotoCount(200)
                    .setShowCamera(true)
                    .setShowGif(true)
                    .setPreviewEnabled(true)
                    .start(ChoosePhotoBookImagesActivity.this, PhotoPicker.REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });


   @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PhotoPicker.REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data != null) {
            mUserSelectedPhotos =
                    data.getStringArrayListExtra(PhotoPicker.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS);
        }
    }
}
```

on click of the next button the the user selected images string arraylist gets passed to the next activity through intent.

PhotoPickingActivity.java

```
 mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhotoPickingActivity.this, PhotoBookListViewActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("USER_SELECTED_IMAGES", mUserSelectedPhotos);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In the next activity which contains the recyclerview, i'm receiving the sent intent within this activity and the received data in the intent is the arraylist of string which contains the filepaths of the images which user selected in the previous activity.

PhotoBookListViewActivity.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
mReceivedImageList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("USER_SELECTED_IMAGES");
```

i'm reading through the mReceivedImageList and converting the filepaths to bitmaps and storing it in the new bitmap arraylist.

PhotoBookListViewActivity.java

```
 final ArrayList<PhotoBookViewModel> bitmapImages = new ArrayList<PhotoBookViewModel>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mImageList.size(); i++) {
        mPhotoUrl = mImageList.get(i).toString();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPhotoUrl);
        bitmapImages.add(new PhotoBookViewModel(myBitmap));
    }
```

passing the bitmapImages arraylist which is the list of bitmap images to the adapter.

PhotoBookListViewActivity.java

```
mPhotoBookViewAdapter = new PhotoBookViewAdapter(PhotoBookListViewActivity.this, bitmapImages);

mPhotoBookViewRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPhotoBookViewAdapter);

mPhotoBookViewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PhotoBookListViewActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

PhotoBookViewModel.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class PhotoBookViewModel {

private Bitmap mImageRes;

public PhotoBookViewModel(Bitmap imageRes) {
    this.mImageRes = imageRes;
}

public Bitmap getImageRes() {
    return mImageRes;
}
}
```

PhotoBookViewAdapter.java

```
public class PhotoBookViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoBookViewAdapter.PhotoViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<PhotoBookViewModel> mData;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private View mImageItemView;
private ArrayList<String> mSelectedPhotos;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Context mContext;

public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView mImageView;

    public PhotoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    }

    public void setData(PhotoBookViewModel currentObj) {
        this.mImageView.setImageBitmap(currentObj.getImageRes());
    }
}

public PhotoBookViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> selectedPhotos) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mSelectedPhotos = selectedPhotos;
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (mSelectedPhotos.get(0).toString());
}

public PhotoBookViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PhotoBookViewModel> mData) {
    this.mData = mData;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PhotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    mImageItemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.photo_book_view_image_item, viewGroup, false);
    PhotoViewHolder photoViewHolder = new PhotoViewHolder(mImageItemView);
    mContext = viewGroup.getContext();
    return photoViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhotoViewHolder photoViewHolder, int position) {
    PhotoBookViewModel currentObj = mData.get(position);
    photoViewHolder.setData(currentObj);;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```

}

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Post some code for a batter undestanding.

Comment: pass the uri with intent

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take a look in the following link, so we can be help more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can store image path in sqlite and then query them in another activity.

Comment: Passing bitmaps of around 500 images might probably lead to a TransactionTooLarge exception. Even if you pass your uri the maximum size of intents that can be passed is 1MB. It would be better if you could use a local db to save those uris and retrieve it in your second activity

Comment: Create an arraylist with the list of images and pass it using intent. Are those images a URL?

Comment: Store those 500 images in your app`s private directory. On the next activity, read the image files. For organizing images, SQLite would be great. Store their absolute path of content URI so you can easily perform queries on the next activity.

Comment: `(1)` Always store images in a directory and their filenames in the database. The path can be a constant if your location its always the same. `(2)` If you application is going to display multiples images in a grid or list, think about having code that creates a small size copy of the original in a separate folder (lets call it `thumbnail`). Those small copies should be used for the grid or list, not the originals. Let me know if it does makes sense to you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for this purpose, it loads images async, and loads the bitmap in the background. There absolutely no need for you to load a bunch of Bitmap-s at all. You just need a list of Uri-s or a list of their String representations

For each image in your list get a Uri String (path to file you already collect in String representation) and then just do something like this

If you stored Uri-s, first get the String value of the Uri for the image (if you already stored String representations od Uri-s skip the next line)

```
String imageUriString = imageUri.getPath();
```

Then use Glide to elegantly load the image to your container

```
Glide.with(myContext)
    .load(new File(imageUriString))
    .into(R.id.image_container);
```

Glide is a rather powerful tool, widely used, even recommended by Google, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel :)

Cheers

Comment: Using Glide is the best approach i dont know why i didnt think of that before thanks @Slobodan Antonijević.

Comment: I used glide in my app. But some large-size images are not loading. For example, in gridView 15 images were loaded & remaining 5 images were shucked in loading. Per image size around 5-10 MB. my code is:
`Glide.with(imgView.context).load(uris[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading).override(400).into(imgView)`.